# Regex get HTML tags by text

Tags: html, regex

I'm having some problems by getting HTML tags by text. I want to get the html tags that contains a string in the text.
this is the code:

```
/(<[a-zA-Z0-9_][^>]*>)(De 7e Hemel)(<\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]*?>)/is
```

How it is working now:

`<b>De 7e Hemel</b> (MATCH)`
`<tr>1. De 7e Hemel</tr> (NO MATCH)`
`<p>This is De 7e Hemel</p> (NO MATCH)`
`<p>De 7e Hemel</p> (MATCH)`

What i want: 
`<b>De 7e Hemel</b> (MATCH)`
`<tr>1. De 7e Hemel</tr> (MATCH)`
`<p>This is De 7e Hemel</p> (MATCH)`
`<p>De 7e Hemel</p> (MATCH)`

So can somebody help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: pls remove the html tags

Comment: @AvinashRaj What do you mean? by this one '`<b>De 7e Hemel</b> (MATCH)`'?

Comment: `regex` is not suitable for parsing HTML. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php/3577662#3577662) to find better tools.

Comment: /<([^<>]+)>.*De 7e Hemel.*<\/\1>/

Comment: Do you also want `<span class="c"><b>Here</b> is De 7e Hemel</span>` to match ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following pattern seems to work:

```
<([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)>[^<]*De 7e Hemel[^<]*<\/\1>
```

I used a backreference to make sure that the opening and closing tags match.  If your flavor of regex does not support backreferences, then you may simply repeat the pattern used in the opening tag.

### Demo

**Edit:**

If your HTML tags could have CSS content inside of them, e.g. `<p color="blue">`, then use this slightly modified pattern:

```
<([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[a-zA-Z0-9_'"= ]*>[^<]*De 7e Hemel[^<]*<\/\1>
```

### Demo

Comment: That group capture at the escape tag though. Beautiful! You have a problem. Inside the tag there are spaces `\s`. I would go with `<(b|tr|p)[^>]*>`

Comment: @S.Kablar No, I won't go with that because your suggestion limits us to only a handful of possible tags.  It doesn't even cover all HTML tags.

Comment: No, no...I was commenting on text and spaces inside the tag `<p ...>`. It should be `<([a-zA-Z]+[^>]*)>`.

Comment: @S.Kablar Do you understand what `[^<]` means?  It means _any_ character which is not an opening bracket.  That includes alphas and spaces of course.

Comment: Do you understand that your regex isn't working for spaces and text inside the tag `<p color="blue"...>`? https://regex101.com/r/KEUsqk/1 You can see it clearly that he wrote it in his own regex `<[a-zA-Z0-9_][^>]*>`.

Comment: @S.Kablar The OP did not make it clear that the HTML tags could have CSS content inside the tags themselves, hence my initial answer did not cover this.  I have provided an updated regex which seems to cover this edge case.

Answer (score 0):

Your current "search term" is glued to your tags. You can loosen that up a bit with `.*` before and after, like so:

```
/(<[a-zA-Z0-9_][^>]*>).*(De 7e Hemel).*(<\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]*?>)/is
```

This will match:
`<b>De 7e Hemel</b>`
`<tr>1. De 7e Hemel</tr>`
`<p>This is De 7e Hemel</p>`
`<p>De 7e Hemel</p>`

Note that it will also match:

`<b>foobar</b><p>De 7e Hemel</p>`
`<p>De 7e Hemel</div>`

To avoid the first scenario, you could modify the `.*` so that it excludes potential tags, like this:

```
/(<[a-zA-Z0-9_][^>]*>)[^<]*(De 7e Hemel)[^<]*(<\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]*?>)/is
```

But this will also exclude results like this:

`<p>1. De 7e Hemel <span style="font-weight: bold">foobar</span></p>`

Which is why regex can be so tricky. You have to carefully think through not only what you do want to match, but also what you don't want to match.

Regex is very bad at matching HTML documents, because it has no sense of context. For extremely simply and well-known (to you) scenarios, you can usually make it work. But if you are trying to scrape websites or scan large documents, I think you'll find that a proper HTML parser is going to save you a lot of pain and frustration.